# Xamarin forms CarouselView swipe only one element at a time

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel, swipe

In my Xamarin.Forms project I need a horizontal carousel swiping of only one element at a time. Is it possible by means of CarouselView? Suggestions?

This is my current CarouselView definition:

```
<CarouselView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Homes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeTemplate}"
    PeekAreaInsets="0" IsSwipeEnabled="True" Loop="False" IsScrollAnimated="False" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0"  />
    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
</CarouselView>
```

Comment: Yes thanks it works in Android. I will test it also in iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the **SnapPointsType**  as `MandatorySingle` .Which indicates the same behavior as Mandatory, but only scrolls one item at a time.

```
<CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
     <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"  />
</CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
```